# Variable api JSON responses to bind to Java Object using Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson-databind

Currently, I am calling third party api which can give the following two variable responses.
I am working in springboot and using Jackson for transformation of REST responses to Java object.
The two variables responses are the following
**error, and success data response combined**

```
{
    "errorCount": 2,
    "errorIndices": [
        0,
        1
    ],
    "data": [
        {
            "errorCode": 901,
            "errorMessage": "IBad data: Check the data",
            "errorData": "xxxx"
        },
        {
            "errorCode": 901,
            "errorMessage": "IBad data: Check the data",
            "errorData": "XZY"
        },
        "fun now"
    ]
}
```

**In case of all success**

```
"{"errorCount": 0,
"errorIndices": [],
"data": [
    "fun now",
    "try later"
]
}
```

The below class I created works for all success scenario,

```
public class ApiResponse {
 @JsonProperty
 private int errorCount;
  @JsonProperty
 private int[] errorIndices;
  @JsonProperty
 private String[] data;

......

}
```

but I am unable to convert the first scenario where error and success results are combined.
Is it possible to create java object that can combined the two scenarios using Jackson api? I need some direction on how to achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to transform the JSON structure, separate String and Object elements before deserialization.

https://github.com/octomix/josson

```
Josson josson = Josson.fromJsonString(
    "{" +
    "    \"errorCount\": 2," +
    "    \"errorIndices\": [" +
    "        0," +
    "        1" +
    "    ]," +
    "    \"data\": [" +
    "        {" +
    "            \"errorCode\": 901," +
    "            \"errorMessage\": \"IBad data: Check the data\"," +
    "            \"errorData\": \"xxxx\"" +
    "        }," +
    "        {" +
    "            \"errorCode\": 901," +
    "            \"errorMessage\": \"IBad data: Check the data\"," +
    "            \"errorData\": \"XZY\"" +
    "        }," +
    "        \"fun now\"" +
    "    ]" +
    "}");
JsonNode node = josson.getNode("field(data[isText()]*, errors: data[isObject()]*)");
System.out.println(node.toPrettyString());
```

**Output**

```
{
  "errorCount" : 2,
  "errorIndices" : [ 0, 1 ],
  "data" : [ "fun now" ],
  "errors" : [ {
    "errorCode" : 901,
    "errorMessage" : "IBad data: Check the data",
    "errorData" : "xxxx"
  }, {
    "errorCode" : 901,
    "errorMessage" : "IBad data: Check the data",
    "errorData" : "XZY"
  } ]
}
```

**Deserialization**

I tested this without error.

```
JsonNode node = josson.getNode("field(data[isText()]*, errors: data[isObject()]*)");
ApiResponse apiResponse = new ObjectMapper().readerFor(ApiResponse.class).readValue(node);
```

Error.java

```
public class Error {
    int errorCode;
    String errorMessage;
    String errorData;

    public Error() {
    }

    public void setErrorCode(int errorCode) {
        this.errorCode = errorCode;
    }

    public void setErrorMessage(String errorMessage) {
        this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
    }

    public void setErrorData(String errorData) {
        this.errorData = errorData;
    }
}
```

ApiResponse.java

```
public class ApiResponse {
    int errorCount;
    int[] errorIndices;
    String[] data;
    Error[] errors;

    public ApiResponse() {
    }

    public void setErrorCount(int errorCount) {
        this.errorCount = errorCount;
    }

    public void setErrorIndices(int[] errorIndices) {
        this.errorIndices = errorIndices;
    }

    public void setData(String[] data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public void setErrors(Error[] errors) {
        this.errors = errors;
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe the way I presented the question. I want to see how the json you put as output represented in some pojo class with Jackson api annotation or using Jackson api

Comment: Define `class Error {int errorCode; String errorMessage; String errorData;...` and add `Error[] errors;` to your `ApiResponse`

Comment: It does not work. Like I said my response could have two variable ones. Adding class Error array gave me the following error 
```SON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `[Ljava.lang.String;` from Object value (token `JsonToken.START_OBJECT`);```

Comment: Appended deserialization details. I tried `new ObjectMapper().readerFor().readValue()` without error.

Answer (score 0):

My target was to use Jackson api, and @Raymond approach is using another library. I found custom deserialization appro[ach here][1]
I used the `SingleAwareListDeserializer` from the article and updated it to the following. In my case the deserializer in case of String response it is just pushing the String to the list.

```
  if (JsonToken.START_ARRAY.equals(token)) {
            while (p.nextToken() != null) {
                if (JsonToken.START_OBJECT.equals(p.currentToken())) {
                    list.add(deserializeObject(p));
                } else  if (JsonToken.VALUE_STRING.equals(p.currentToken())) {
                 //added this part in case of string response
                list.add(p.getValueAsString());
                } 
            }
        }
```

I have the following classes to map the response.

```
public class Data {

    private Data() {
        
    }

    private String errorCode;
    private String errorMessage;
    private String errorData;
    
    public String getErrorCode() {
        return errorCode;
    }
    public void setErrorCode(String errorCode) {
        this.errorCode = errorCode;
    }
    public String getErrorMessage() {
        return errorMessage;
    }
    public void setErrorMessage(String errorMessage) {
        this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
    }
    public String getErrorData() {
        return errorData;
    }
    public void setErrorData(String errorData) {
        this.errorData = errorData;
    }

    
    
}
```

Below ApiResponse

```
public class ApiResponse {

    int errorCount;
    int[] errorIndices;
    
    @JsonDeserialize(using = SingleAwareListDeserializer.class)
    List<Data> data;
    
    public int getErrorCount() {
        return errorCount;
    }
    public void setErrorCount(int errorCount) {
        this.errorCount = errorCount;
    }
    public int[] getErrorIndices() {
        return errorIndices;
    }
    public void setErrorIndices(int[] errorIndices) {
        this.errorIndices = errorIndices;
    }

    public List<Data> getData() {
        return data;
    }
    public void setData(List<Data> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
    
}
```

For testing I used the following,

```
public void deserializeTest() {
       //case response has a generic List with Data object type and string //value mix
        String objStringWithError = "\n"
                + "{\n"
                + "    \"errorCount\": 2,\n"
                + "    \"errorIndices\": [\n"
                + "        0,\n"
                + "        1\n"
                + "    ],\n"
                + "    \"data\": [\n"
                + "        \"try now\",\n"
                + "        {\n"
                + "            \"errorCode\": 901,\n"
                + "            \"errorMessage\": \"IBad data: Check the data\",\n"
                + "            \"errorData\": \"xxxx\"\n"
                + "        },\n"
                + "        {\n"
                + "            \"errorCode\": 901,\n"
                + "            \"errorMessage\": \"IBad data: Check the data\",\n"
                + "            \"errorData\": \"XZY\"\n"
                + "        },\n"
                + "        \"fun now\"\n"
                + "    ]\n"
                + "}";
//case response have errorcount, errorIndices fields and array of Strings
        String objStringWithNoError = "{\"errorCount\": 0,\n"
                + "\"errorIndices\": [],\n"
                + "\"data\": [\n"
                + "    \"fun now\",\n"
                + "    \"try later\"\n"
                + "]}";
//case response is only array of strings
        String stringArray = "{\n"
                + "\"data\": [\n"
                + "    \"fun now\",\n"
                + "    \"try later\"\n"
                + "]}";

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        ApiResponse model = null;
        try {
            model = mapper.readValue(objStringWithError, ApiResponse.class);
        } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The deserializer works in all three cases; I only mentioned first case in my initial question. I have a mix of data types-- a Data type object and String type object, but if the response is all String I still also getting List of String in the ApiResponse data field which converted to List object. What I understood is that the deserializer is creating a generic List object and assigning it to List. I could not  create field under Data class to hold string value when Deserializer is within this condition.
`if(JsonToken.VALUE_STRING.equals(p.currentToken()))`
[1]: https://dzone.com/articles/consuming-variable-responses-in-jackson